# I have Codeigniter project i don't know to write Route

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'home';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['(:any)'] = "home/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1/$1/$1/$1";
$route['project'] = "project";
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/$1';
```

I have default Home Controller and I added extra $1 parameter is working.
Home Controller fully is working but same like I want Project controller

```
$route['project'] = "project"; Is working
```

but

```
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/$1';
```

Its Not Working i don't know why please help me Advance

Comment: The actual think is i tried $route['newproject/project_listing'] = "newproject/project_listing";
$route['newproject/updateproject/(:any)'] = "newproject/updateproject/$1"; its not working with new controller

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


$route['project'] = "project";
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/$1';
$route['project/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'project/$1/$2';

/*this should be after the project route setting or in the last 
 according to the precedence of url it always call the first match */

$route['(:any)'] = "home/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$1/$1/$1/$1";
```

Just a suggestion your route for `home` controller should be like this :

```
/*home should start with name home where first `(:any)` tends to method name and 
second `(:any)` tends to parameters*/

$route['home'] = "home";
$route['home/(:any)'] = "home/$1";
$route['home/(:any)/(:any)'] = "home/$1/$2";

/*you can add many more like this*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You never mention method name in route, this is why routes are not working

Try this

```
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/method_name/$1'
```

Also `home` routes should like `home/method_name/$1`, `home/index/$1/$1` etc

Comment: please see my comments

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
$route['project'] = "project";
```

it will run your `project` controller `index` function, so it will work

```
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/method_name/$1'
```

if you call like this will search `project` controller `method_name` function and you should pass `parameter`. because you have added `(:any)` in routes

If you use `(:any)` or `(:num)` in the routes, you should capture parameter in the function.

example.

```
$route['project/(:any)'] = 'project/method_name/$1'    
function method_name($param1){
   //your code
}

$route['project/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'project/method_name/$1/$2'    
function method_name($param1, $param2){
   //your code
}
```

You can simply use `(.*)` in route for unlimited parameters. and you don't need to capture the parameter in the function. check below.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'home';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['(.*)'] = "home";
$route['project'] = "project";
$route['project/(.*)'] = 'project';
```

use `$this->uri->segment()` to capture the unlimited params in the function

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
        $param1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $param2 = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $param3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
}

class Project extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
        $param1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $param2 = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $param3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
}
```